# Intersection of a closure

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, notation

What is the intersection of a closure?

That is, $U$ is a open set, then what is:

[image]

Comment: What are you looking for? relation to closure of intersections?

Comment: The notation means: *Intersect the closures of all open sets $U$ which contain $x$.* The point $x$ is fixed, and $U$ is variable. Did you encounter this term in the context of Hausdorff spaces? In a Hausdorff space, this intersection is equal to $\{x\}$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes, I'm just starting out in Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: So, is everything clear now?

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yeah. It's most of the time just misunderstanding of notation that causes misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation
$$
\bigcap_{U\text{ open}, x\in U}\bar U
$$
means: *Intersect the closures of all open sets $U$ which contain $x$.* The point $x$ is fixed, and $U$ is variable. Alternatively, you could use the notation
$$
\bigcap \{\bar U \mid U\text{ open}, x\in U\}
$$
In a Hausdorff space, this intersection is equal to $\{x\}$, and this equality (for all $x\in X$) is also sufficient for $X$ to be a Hausdorff space.